# Coding ordered sets

Tags: coq

As for having Coq programming experience, 
I'd like to know if there are any other ways to code, instead of my coding, preorder relations for using them in checking [a function is non-decreasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function). I replaced the datatypes and functions of my program to simple ones in the code below. 
`mydata` is a set with a preorder relation (i.e. with a reflexive and transitive relation)  and is  the range of the function `mappingFunction` which maps nat numbers to `mydata`. I couldn't define preorder relation on mydata when coding theorem  `mappingFunction_isIncreasing`, so as a solution I mapped `mydata` to nat numbers through `dataparts_toNat` to enable me to define the preorder relation among them. I wonder if there is any other ways to do this program, for example without having `dataparts_toNat`. Thank you.

```
 (*defining the datatype*)
Inductive mydata : Set :=
  | part1 : mydata
  | part2 : mydata
  |part3 :mydata.

(* mapping to nats to have
        preorder relation(part1<part2<part3 and part1=part1 and part2=part2 and part3=part3)*)
Definition dataparts_toNat (n:mydata):nat :=
   match n with
          |part1 => 0
          |part2 => 1
          |part3 => 2
    end.

(* a sample function from nat to mydata which is always increasing or not changing*)
Definition mappingFunction
  (a1:nat): mydata :=
        match a1 with 
           |0=> part1
           |S(0) => part2
           |_ => part3
         end.    
Theorem mappingFunction_isIncreasing: forall(a1 a2: nat)(data1 data2: mydata),
   a1<=a2 -> (mappingFunction a1= data1 )/\(mappingFunction a2= 
data2) -> ((dataparts_toNat data1) <= dataparts_toNat(data2)).
Proof.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(* The definition of mydata again, for completeness *)
Inductive mydata : Set :=
| part1 : mydata
| part2 : mydata
| part3 : mydata.
```

You can define a comparison as a boolean function `mydata -> mydata -> bool`:

```
Definition le_mydata_dec (d1 d2 : mydata) : bool :=
  match d1, d2 with
  | part1, _ => true
  | part2, (part2 | part3) => true
  | part3, part3 => true
  | _, _ => false
  end.
```

And from that, derive a comparison relation `mydata -> mydata -> Prop` (this is only one way, sometimes it's more convenient to define `le_mydata` as an `Inductive` proposition).

```
Definition le_mydata (d1 d2 : mydata) : Prop :=
  le_mydata_dec d1 d2 = true.
```

The mapping function is the same (renamed `f` for brevity):

```
(* a sample function from nat to mydata which is always increasing or not changing*)
Definition f
  (a1:nat): mydata :=
        match a1 with 
           |0=> part1
           |S(0) => part2
           |_ => part3
         end.
```

Now this is monotonicity:

```
Theorem f_isMonotonic: forall(a1 a2: nat),
   a1<=a2 -> le_mydata (f a1) (f a2).
Proof.
Abort.
```

You can use notations to replace `le_mydata` with a prettier `<=`. Here we are careful to not hide the preexisting notation `<=` for comparison of `nat`, by assigning this new notation to a new scope `mydata_scope`, delimited with the key `mydata`.

```
Infix "<=" := le_mydata : mydata_scope.
Delimit Scope mydata_scope with mydata.
(* now we can write  (x <= y)%mydata  instead of  le_mydata x y *)
```

The monotonicity theorem again, using that notation:

```
Theorem f_isMonotonic: forall(a1 a2: nat),
   a1<=a2 -> (f a1 <= f a2)%mydata.
Proof.
Abort.
```

Comment: In my code `dataparts_toNat` maps `mydata` to nat because they have preorder relation of <= (i.e. transitive and reflexive) but  you defined `le_mydata_dec` which does not show that transitivity is held and requires other lemmas. What's more, for datatypes of bigger size, for example with ten constructors, it needs to consider a lot of other cases.

Comment: For larger datatypes you can use tactics or plugins to automate the implementation and verification of standard relations (though I don't know of any widely available implementation).